# Failed to proceed when loging in to azure toolkit plugin in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, azure

When logging in into azure plugin (new installation) to eclipse using any of the options (Oauth/ device)

I was able to login in the browser and enter the code generated from the plugin in eclipse and select the account, but then back to eclipse

It fails and it shows this error:

**Failed to proceed, org.eclipse.swt.SWTException Invalid thread access.**

EDIT: A policy blocks the files, after elevating the access it's all good.

Comment: Look in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory to see if there is a more detailed message. [Edit] your question to show us the extra detail.

Answer (score 0):

A policy blocks the files, after elevating the access it's all good.